# "Namespace could not be found" with ASP 5 and local project references

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball9000/tree/Auth and I have made a reference from my startup project FoosballApi2 () to Models project.

But when I try to build I get

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Error CS0246 The type or
>   namespace name 'Models' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) FoosballApi2.DNX Core 5.0
>   C:\Git\Foosball9000\FoosballApi2\Controllers\LeaderboardController.cs
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0246  The type or
>   namespace name 'LeaderboardViewEntry' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  FoosballApi2.DNX
>   Core
>   5.0   C:\Git\Foosball9000\FoosballApi2\Controllers\LeaderboardController.cs

In VS 2015 I get no errors at all until I build, so no read lines or anything 
[image]

Comment: I have seen that issue when trying to add a reference to a class library project. Add it as a class library (package) project.

Comment: You may need to manually delete any `obj` and `bin` folders within each project in your solution and try rebuilding.

Comment: @StephenBrickner That worked thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: @StephenBrickner please add that as an answer so the question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen that issue when trying to add a reference to a class library project. Add it as a class library (package) project.